# Ожидающему подтверждения комментария стоит запрет на новый комментарий

Tags: wordpress

Можно ли в `wordpress` реализовать, чтобы при отправке комментария этот же пользователь больше не смог отправлять комментарии, пока модератор не подтвердит его первый коммент? Можете статейки подкинуть или написать хук

Comment: Вы можете использовать хук comment_post

Comment: Запрещать категорически не стоит - может юзер дополнить захочет. А вот автоматом на модерацию кинуть - другое дело. А это штатная функция ВП

Comment: @SeVlad сейчас реализовано автоматом на модерацию. Не могу понять как реализовать уведобление для пользователя оставившего комментарий, чтобы вывелся вместо формы блок с уведомлением "ТВОЙ КОММЕНТАРИЙ ОТПРАВЛЕН СКОРО ОН ПОЯВИТСЯ ТУТ". А после подтверждения или удаления администратором, форма вернулась обратно

Comment: Так оно по дефолту и есть.

Comment: @SeVlad сейчас у меня по дефолту и не так. Комментирование можно сколько угодно

Comment: Да, "можно сколько угодно", но он на сайте не появиться, и юзер увидит предупреждение.